# Can mediaelement-and-play core JS be dequeued?

Tags: core, optimization

I'd like to understand what is the purpose of the WordPress core javascript file /wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js

I am asking that because it weighs 136KBytes and I'd like to understand if I can avoid to load it for 
certain websites that eventually do not use that functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

It's for the audio and video players used by the `[audio]` and `[video]` shortcodes, as well as the Audio and Video widgets, but *not* the Audio and Video blocks. The script will only be enqueued if you are using the shortcodes or widgets.